# Difference between Sith and practices of Kylo and Snoke?

Tags: star-wars, sith, kylo-ren, snoke

Supposedly Snoke and Kylo are not Sith this being so that the prophecy of Anakin Skywalker ending the Sith could be maintained while still allowing the sequel trilogy to happen.

But what are the actual differences in doctrine between the actual Sith order and this new group that has red lightsabers, likes throne rooms and tries to conquer the universe just as the Sith did?

Is there a passage in the novelisation or something that explains this?

Comment: Technically, Anakin Skywalker killing Palpatine and then dying ends "the" Sith line that was established by Darth Bane - always two, a master and an apprentice. Of course, there are other dark side users and very like some original Sith teaching are known there, too. But the original line ended with Darth Vader.

Comment: I don't recall if the exact words of the prophecy were ever revealed. What we know is that Anakin was supposed to be the chosen one to bring balance to the force. The jedi interpreted that to mean the destruction of the sith. The true meaning of "balance" is very debatable.

Comment: They like merchandizing more.

Comment: Kylo Ren was beaten by an untrained light side user, whereas the Sith could actually defeat Jedi (many of them).